# Convention for multi-view iOS application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, view

I'm new to developing iOS applications, but I have a quick question about implementing a multi-view application.

I'm assuming to create an application with multiple views I must create my view controller classes, and instantiate all of them within my appDelegate class in order to switch back and forth between views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe.

With a UINavigationController you typically instantiate them in your current view controller, in response to some user action, then push the new controller onto the the UINavigationController stack.

If you're using a UITabBarController, you need to instantiate them before you put them in the tab bar, so you might do that in the app delegate in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.

It depends on how you plan to switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend Casey..[This](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/) tutorial will explain it..No need to create all viewControllers in appDelegate.

Comment: I'm familiar with it, but I'm basically just trying to teach myself the hard way so I truly understand what's going on.

Comment: You don't really want to be trying to do multiple views without a navigation controller or tab bar controller. All you'll learn is there's a reason they exist.

Comment: Instantiating everything in the app delegate is not much of a "hard way" than it is a "youre-doing-it-wrong way". A UINavigationController, or maybe a UITabBar or something similar, should be the way to go.